# React Native MapView rotate map with camera heading

Tags: android, ios, dictionary, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to rotate a map in React Native's **<MapView>** but haven't been able to find a description on how to rotate a map according to the heading of the camera. The tutorial states:

> When this property is set to true and a valid camera is associated with the map, the camera’s heading angle is used to rotate the plane of the map around its center point.

So I came as far as:

```
<MapView
          style={styles.map}
          onRegionChange={this._onRegionChange}
          onRegionChangeComplete={this._onRegionChangeComplete}
          region={this.state.mapRegion}
          annotations={this.state.annotations}
          rotateEnabled={true}
```

But there is no explanation on how a camera is associated with the map.

Can anyone help with this issue please?

Answer (score 0):

### You can use animateCamera

```
const mapRef = useRef(null);

  const animate_point=async()=>{
      mapRef.current.animateCamera({
        heading:60,
        zoom: 17,
        center: {
          latitude:latitude_coordinate,
        longitude:longitude_coordinate ,
    },
    pitch: 45,})
 
  } ->pass this function whenever you want. like in onRegionChange function

 <MapView
        ref={mapRef}
onRegionChange={animate_point}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use camera property for that.
You can read the [documentation](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/HEAD/docs/mapview.md) for more information.